# Cannot update div without reloading page through jquery to display json data

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I'm fetching the "like count" from django backend and I'm adding the right value in the respective field. However I need to reload the page in order for the value to be updated.
The problem is that the html code includes classes, not ids since the idea is to have a lot of "similar" posts (like a feed of posts).

I've tried different ways of reloading just the div that includes the like button but have failed so far. any ideas would be appreciated!

I want to handle the reloading in the frontend

```
$(document).on('click', ".like_post", function(e){
    var self = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: self.data("url"),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            self.children("p").text(data["count"]);
    },
    });
});
```

I'm attaching the html code, imagine each "card" as each of the post generated on the site:

```
<div class="card>
 <div class="card-heading"></div>
 <div class="card-body"></div>
 <div class="card-actions">
  <a class="btn .like_post" data-url"">
   <ul>
    <li><p>like count</p></li>
    <li>like image</li>
   </ul>
  </a>
  <a class="btn .share_post" data-url"">
    <ul>
      <li>share count</li>
      <li>share image</li>
    </ul>
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure self.children("p") is finding that "p" you want to find?

Comment: *I've tried different ways of reloading just the div that includes the like button but have failed so far.*  Yes, but how have you failed we need to understand what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: Please post your html code

Comment: @yBrodsky yes, self.children("p") is finding the p tag i want, because when I refresh the page, the count value is updated under the p tag

Comment: @DelightedD0D I tried reloading the div using jquery's load method, but the content disappears, i'd need guidance on how to implement it

Comment: Does `self` have descendant `p` elements when the function is triggered?  They're not in the HTML above.  Also, as `like_post` is an `<a>`, you might want to add `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: @sideroxylon my bad, it's in the first li tag, I forgot to add it here

Comment: Can you see the response data in the console?  Try `data.count`.

Comment: @sideroxylon yes, i can see it in the console, but only after reloading the page it is displayed under the p tag

Comment: You could test by adding it to a different element.  Without seeing the response data it's a bit difficult, but data.count would be the more usual way to get the part you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two issues in your code and it worked after correcting them.

1. anchor tag has the class as `.like_post` instead of `like_post` in
   `<a class="btn .like_post" data-url"">` which didn't trigger the
   `click` event
2. `self.children("p")` is not returning the element since the
   `self.children()` is returning the immediate child `<ul>`. Hence, it
   has been changed to `self.find("p")`.

Also add `event.stopPropagation()` if your anchor tag has any `href` element and make sure your `ajax` request returns data.

Note: To check this, I have commented `$.ajax` code and used `setTimeout` to simultate the ajax response waiting.

```js
$(document).on('click', ".like_post", function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
    var self = $(this);
    /*$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: self.data("url"),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            self.find("p").text(data["count"]);
    },
    });*/
  
  setTimeout(function(){
    var data = {count: 10};
    //console.log(self.children());
    self.find("p").text(data["count"]);
  }, 500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
 <div class="card-heading"></div>
 <div class="card-body"></div>
 <div class="card-actions">
  <a class="btn like_post" data-url"">
   <ul>
    <li><p>like count</p></li>
    <li>like image</li>
   </ul>
  </a>
  <a class="btn .share_post" data-url"">
    <ul>
      <li>share count</li>
      <li>share image</li>
    </ul>
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Error 1 was just a typo, but Error 2 solved everything! thanks so much ;)